# Как скрыть ссылку, если прошло 24 часа с определенного времени?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Есть задача скрыть ссылку и элемент на странице, если прошли сутки с определенного момента времени.

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Формат времени доступен в двух видах:

- ```
  [DATE_CREATE] => 03.09.2012 16:38:12
  ```
- ```
  [DATE_CREATE_UNIX] => 1346675892
  ```

Comment: Лучше наверно сразу считать, когда нужно убрать ссылку. А потом через крон каждые 30 минут (или чаще) проверять и убирать ссылки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If (time() >= [DATE_CREATE_UNIX]+24*60*60) echo "Прошли сутки";
```

Думаю смысл понятен.

Comment: Получается умножать таймштамп на 24, 60 и 60? Ответ ведь выйдет некорректным.

Comment: Не у множить, а прибавить.

    [DATE_CREATE_UNIX]+86400; //86400 кол-во секунд в сутках

Comment: evlanoff, Спасибо!

Comment: Да, прибавить, сорри, заработался.